# помогите со строками

Tags: c++, строки

С клавиатуры вводится слово. Определить сколько раз в веденном слове встречается "нн".

Помогите найти ошибки. Вроде норм расписал но почему то не считает:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    int    n = 0;
    char * s;
    s = new char[100];

    cin >> s;

    while ((s = strstr(s, "нн")) != NULL) {
        n++;
        s += 2
    }
    delete s;
    cout << "count words:" << n;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Не считает" это как? Водку пьянствует и драки хулиганит?

Comment: не считает количество нн

Comment: Понятно. Не считает количество "нн". Вместо этого оно водку пьянствует и драки хулиганит.

Comment: вы уверены, что ваш код не работает? проверил, у меня он отлично работает. Ну и не забывайте прибраться после себя, имею ввиду память, выделенную под `char* s`

Comment: А `delete` кто будет делать?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вероятно, ОСь, когда программа завершится. ;-) `delete`? Не, не слышал!

Comment: исправил посмотрите так должно быть?

Comment: @user198928 `delete` за цикл выынесите

Comment: @user198928 точнее даже сохраните исходный указатель и его удаляйте после цикла

Answer (score 2):

Проблема данного кода заключается вовсе не в коде, а в кодировке исходного файла. Кодировка консоли операционной системы отличается от кодировки файла, поэтому коды русских букв различаются. Чтобы всё работало правильно, нужно чтобы кодировка исходного файла совпадала с кодировкой консоли. В случае *Windows* кодировка консоли по умолчанию - ***CP866*** (кодовая страница 866). Пересохраните исходник в этой кодировке и всё заработает.

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: @user198928 Обратитесь к документации на используемый Вами текстовый редактор или IDE.

Comment: как к нему обратиться я просто новичок ещё не очень понимаю что мне нужно сделать можете расписать по шагам

Comment: @user198928 Для начала неплохо бы узнать, как Ваш редактор называется. Или Вам надо объяснить как определить название программы, которая у Вас запущена?

Comment: microsoft visual studio

Comment: @user198928 А вот и х.з. Не юзаю такое. Может, кто другой подскажет.

Comment: @user198928, File -> Save as, откроется диалог. Там внизу кнопка, где можно выбрать «Save with encoding» — там и выбирайте нужную кодировку. Ещё можно поставить notepad++, там это тоже легко делается